# How to export org file to HTML file when save?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I want to export my org files to HTML files to certain directory when save.
I can use Emacs and Org-mode but I don't know Elisp.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Note: The below was written for Emacs 23. Check the answer by @AndreasSpindler for an up-to-date solution.**

Emacs has a couple of *hooks* which are called in certain events.  The hook you are looking for is probably the `after-save-hook`.  Just set it to the function you want to run every time you save the file.  In your case this would be `org-html-export-to-html`.

There are many ways to do this, but the following method is probably the fastest and doesn't involve any "real" elisp.  Put the following lines somewhere in your org file:

```
# Local variables:
# after-save-hook: org-html-export-to-html
# end:
```

The next time you open that file, you'll get a warning and be asked if the local variable should be set (as that's potentially unsafe, but not a problem here).  Press <kbd>y</kbd> and everything should just work.

Answer (score 11):

With Org-Mode 8.3 and Emacs 24.5.1 the accepted answer creates a pseudo-buffer `*Org HTML Export*` that you have to save manually, while the key `C-c C-e h h` more conveniently saves the file directly.

To really auto-export in the background try the following code:

```
# Local variables:
# eval: (add-hook 'after-save-hook 'org-html-export-to-html t t)
# end:
```

You can combine this solution with the following function in your `.emacs`:

```
(defun toggle-html-export-on-save ()
  "Enable or disable export HTML when saving current buffer."
  (interactive)
  (when (not (eq major-mode 'org-mode))
    (error "Not an org-mode file!"))
  (if (memq 'org-html-export-to-html after-save-hook)
      (progn (remove-hook 'after-save-hook 'org-html-export-to-html t)
             (message "Disabled org html export on save"))
    (add-hook 'after-save-hook 'org-html-export-to-html nil t)
    (set-buffer-modified-p t)
    (message "Enabled org html export on save")))
```

Comment: The following slightly adapted version, enables asynchronous exporting: `# eval: (add-hook 'after-save-hook (lambda () (org-html-export-to-html t)) t t)` That feels more like an auto-preview when the document is saved. It’s useful if the org file contains source blocks that are executed or with LaTeX export. This enables you to save and continue writing without having to wait for the export to be finished.

Comment: Im not emacs expert but when I tried to use above aproach for (org-reveal-export-to-html) I found that it registers hook multiple times (I recived lots of errors even after I changed implementation). At the end I ended up with `# after-save-hook: (lambda () (org-reveal-export-to-html) t)`. and not `eval`

Comment: How do you sop emacs prompting to allow this eval in the org-source?

Answer (score 1):

The command for this is

```
C-c C-e h h     (org-html-export-to-html)
```

Export as an HTML file. For an Org file myfile.org, the HTML file will be myfile.html. The file will be overwritten without warning. C-c C-e h o Export as an HTML file and immediately open it with a browser.

[Reference](http://orgmode.org/manual/HTML-Export-commands.html#HTML-Export-commands)

Comment: otherwise i suggest looking at this tutorial http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-publish-html-tutorial.html

Comment: This has nothing to do with the original question which was how to automatically export when saving an org-mode buffer.